# Priortizing LAN over WLAN won't work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I'm trying to set my LAN internet as the main one for playing video games, and my WLAN one for streaming, I followed many tutorials (which they all explain the same thing) on setting metrics, I have set my LAN to 5 and my WLAN to 10, but my computer still prioritizes my WLAN for some reason, I could really use your help and thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

Set both LAN and WAN configurations to Automatic Metric.

Exit from this and run TCP/IP Reset:

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

(2) ipconfig /flushdns

(3) restart the computer and test now that LAN takes priority over WAN.

If you have made other changes, you may also wish to run DISM and SFC and then reset TCP/IP again.

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

(4) SFC /SCANNOW

(5) Restart when all the above is complete, run TCP/IP Reset again, restart and test LAN and WAN operation.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply
I tried all of the above, but WiFi is still a priority
https://prnt.sc/1qcsc37

Comment: If the above (Reset TCP/IP and also DISM) does not fix the issue, there is something gone wrong in your operating system.

Comment: I fixed that, apparently the problem was the fact that I had a static IP on my LAN card, I changed that to DHCP and now it works properly, thank you again for your help.